# Outgoing network performance (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

There an external HTTP server (located somewhere in the US), which we must communicate with. We use AWS EC2 instances.

While we can buy a "bigger instance" to improve the internal network performance, is there a way to lessen (optimize?) the roundtrip time between our EC2 instance and the external server? Are therer any tools that could be useful?

Comment: Did you discover the use of CloudFront and edge locations with your scenario?

Comment: Are you saturating the existing network for the EC2?  How do you know you need a faster "pipe" to the EC2?  Or is the remote server just slow?

Comment: @stdunbar When I send a single query to the remote server from my home network, it is much faster than when running on an AWS EC2 (regardless of where the ec2 is hosted).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what type of EC2 instance you use which is a big factor determining the network performance.

You also said

> from my home network, it is much faster than when running on an AWS EC2 (regardless of where the ec2 is hosted)

I know nothing about your home network and your EC2 instance config so this is  hard to judge but I'd expect, on average, the EC2 instance having faster network than what's available on the end user's site.

It's also not 100% clear what you are measuring. You said "round trip time" so you are only interested in end-to-end latency? Any particular throughput requirements?

That said, here's a useful cheat sheet which you can download and check your instance type: https://cloudonaut.io/ec2-network-performance-cheat-sheet/

Furthermore, you can use `iperf` (or `iperf3`) to perform some experiments on both sides of the connection:

- https://www.tecmint.com/test-network-throughput-in-linux/
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/